# Loop stop condition

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I have a countdown macro with start and stop button. I would like to fix stop time, so when counter is zero, it shouldn't start again, so `Loop Until StopTimer` should be replaced. I tried `EndTime - Now = 0` as condition, but it isn't working.

```
Sub Countdown()
  Const Seconds = 10
  Dim EndTime As Double
  StopTimer = False
  Do
    If EndTime - Now < 0 Then
      EndTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, Seconds)
    End If
    Range("A1") = EndTime - Now
    DoEvents
  Loop Until StopTimer
End Sub
```

Comment: This depends on when you want to stop looping. Keep your code as you show, but just set `StopTimer = True` when you want to stop looping.

Comment: `EndTime - Now = 0` could be correct in a condition, that set variable to `TRUE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Countdown()
  Const Seconds = 10
  Dim EndTime As Double
  EndTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, Seconds)
  StopTimer = False
  Do
    If EndTime - Now <= 0 Then
      StopTimer = True
    End If
    Range("A1") = EndTime - Now
    DoEvents
  Loop Until StopTimer
End Sub
```

Comment: I see, it is really simple! Thanks!